Проект Godot стартует только после нескольких попыток
Проект запускается только после нескольких попыток.
Спецификации:

Godot: v4.2.2
Ryzen 3 5300U
16 gb RAM
Windows 11
Radeon Graphics

Я пробовал запускать проект с разными режимами рендеринга, но только gl работает нормально. Я бы подумал, что моя система не поддерживает vulkan, но в интернете я нашел информацию, что там, где vulkan не поддерживается, проект просто не запускается. У меня он запускается после нескольких попыток.

А что конкретно происходит во время попыток, при которых «не запускается»?

Добавьте лог из консоли, пожалуйста

Во время попыток, при которых «не запускается», запускается просто черное окно, даже без лого годота, затем проходить секунд 5-10 и окно закрывается.
Также объясните как посмотреть логи из консоли?
